# Centering inner text, and text inside my circles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Edit: I have managed to centered the text for outer circles using, but still having trouble with the main text `primary industry...`

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

I have a bunch of circles being dynamically rendered.

I'm trying to get `primary industry ...` text to be centered of all the circles

Here's how it actually looks

[image]

I've tried to replicate the behaviour in codepen but the layout is slightly off

https://codesandbox.io/embed/circles-88tzy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

My real code looks like this

```
const CircleMenu = ({ question }) => {
  

  const graph = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const circlegraph = graph.current
    const circleElements = circlegraph.childNodes // not an array

    let angle = 360 - 90
    let dangle = 360 / circleElements.length

    for (let i = 0; i < circleElements.length; i++) {
      let circle = circleElements[i]
      angle += dangle
      circle.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${circlegraph.clientWidth /
        2}px) rotate(-${angle}deg)`
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container>
      <CenterText>{question.primaryCircle.text}</CenterText>
      <CircleContainer>
        <div className="circlegraph" ref={graph}>
          {question.choices.map(item => (
            <div className="circle" key={item.id}>
              <p>{item.text}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </CircleContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}

const CenterText = styled.p`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 800px;
`

const CircleContainer = styled.div`
  .circlegraph {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: calc(100px / 2 + 0px);
  }

  .circlegraph:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* border: 2px solid teal; */
    width: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
    height: calc(100% - 2px * 2);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .circlegraph .circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: calc(-100px / 2);
    background: teal;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use flex properties for your circles to align them with ease. Example:

```
.ciclegraph .circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

As for the `h1` it is currently relative to the App and not the circles' container. You can alter your HTML structure to put the `h1` in that container but you can also just add pseudo after if you wish to retain the structure - if you do so, just remove the `h1`. If this is for SEO purposes, I do not recommend the latter. But you should get the idea.

```
.ciclegraph:after {
  content: "SOME BASIC TEXT";
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/circles-3eq19?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it :)